# Positioning Input doesn't Take Effect

Tags: css, jsx

Hi am doing a project called todo-list. But it seems like when I do padding, margin or position it doesn't work. Thanks!

CreateArea.jsx -

```
import react from 'react';

//FINAL STEP: Create a database that store info about the todolist tasks!

function CreateArea() {
    return (
        <div className="mainbox">
            <div className="inputdiv">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

part of styles.css -

```
.mainbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: #f5ba13;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

And it looks like this -
[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRbI0.png)

Comment: The CSS you posted is for the div, not the input. And it looks like it's being applied just fine

Comment: @j08691 when I make the property right - `.inputdiv {
  right: 70px;
}` it doesn't move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the properties `left, top, right and bottom` you need to change your default position which is static, you can use absolute or relative instead. If you choose `absolute` you need to set the parent div to position relative, otherwise, your element will be positioned in relation to the `<body>`.

**Example using position absolute:**

```
   .mainbox {
       position: relative
       width: 300px;
       height: 650px;
       background-color: #f5ba13;
       box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       border-radius: 35px;
       padding-left: 300px;
       margin: 20px auto;
     }
           
    .inputdiv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 200px;
        }
```